# Single Sign on in native android apps using SAML v2.0

Tags: android, asp.net, authentication, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

How to implement single sign on (SAMLv2.0) native android mobile apps?
I would like to get a generalized platform that support different identity providers such as Okta, ADFS, Azure AD ...

Comment: your question is too generalized. consider making it more detailed.

Comment: Actually I would like to know how to implement SSO on native mobile apps.

Comment: SAML was simply not designed for modern application types, such as SPAs and mobile apps. Instead of fighting the protocol, use OAuth 2.0 and OIDC for these application types.

Comment: did you happen to figure it out? Even I am stuck with the same problem

Comment: Appdome has some solutions - https://www.appdome.com/enterprise-mobile-apps/mobile-iam/appdome-mobile-sso/